# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python

I'm getting this error, can someone show me where I went wrong.

```
import requests
import time
with open("C:\\temp\\cars.txt", 'r') as myfile:
  data1 = myfile.read()

searchKey = "ford="
searchEndKey = '"' 
auto = data1.text[data1.text.find(searchKey) + len(searchKey):
                  data1.text.find(searchEndKey, data1.text.find(searchKey) + 
                                                len(searchKey) + 1)]

with open("C:\\temp\\cars2.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("C:\\temp\\cars3.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('ford=', 'ford='+auto))
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Why do you think a `str` would have a `text` attribute?

Comment: Start by removing the `.text`

Comment: Thank you, that worked - "Start by removing the .text"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted above, removed the .text
Working now